# Why is the external DTD not validating to the XML file?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I needed the external DTD to validate with the XML file and 'choices' 'phones' and 'phone' keep appearing with an error. I know it has to do with my elements order but I cannot figure it out.

I edited the. elements phone and phones, I believe it is validating now

DTD

```
     [
        <!ELEMENT smartphones (choices+)>

        <!ELEMENT choices (phones,phone,name,company,price,storage,description)>
        <!ATTLIST choices phones NMTOKENS #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT phones (phone)>
    <!ATTLIST phones CDATA #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT phone (name,company,price,storage,description)>
    <!ATTLIST phone NMTOKENS #REQUIRED>

        <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>

        <!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>

        <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>

        <!ELEMENT storage (#PCDATA)>

        <!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>

        ]>

<!-- XML -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<!DOCTYPE smartphones SYSTEM "Vocab1DTD.dtd">

<smartphones>

<choices>Smart Phones

   <phones>
      <phone>
         <name> </name>
         <company> </company>
         <price> </price>
         <storage> </storage>
         <description> </description>
      </phone>

  </phones>
</choices>
</smartphones>
```

Comment: The actual error would help, but I'm guessing it's the `[` and `]>` in the DTD file. Remove those and try again. If that doesn't work, add the error you're getting.

Comment: Nevermind. I see now that there are a lot more issues. Which is correct? The DTD or the XML?

Comment: the XML is correct, the DTD is what I'm having trouble with

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated DTD that works with your XML as-is.

Small comment about the XML: It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have "Smart Phones" as text in `choices`; that can be inferred by `choices` being a child of `smartphones`. Also, `choices` and `phones` seem redundant; what is the purpose of having both?

Let me know if you have questions on the changes I made.

**Vocab1DTD.dtd**

```
<!ELEMENT smartphones (choices+)>
<!ELEMENT choices (#PCDATA|phones)*>
<!ELEMENT phones (phone+)>
<!ELEMENT phone (name,company,price,storage,description)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT storage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
```